# Sed to replace directory path with condition

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

In My file these are the two entries are there

```
cat a.txt
/a/d/f
/a/d/f/
```

I want to replace this both to /a/d/f/g

I have tried various sed formation like below

```
sed -i -e 's|/a/d/f|/a/d/f/g/|g' -e 's|/a/d/f/|/a/d/f/g/|g' a.txt
```

But this replaces like this

```
more a.txt
/a/d/f/g/g/
/a/d/f/g/g//
```

Please share your ideas if we can put some other condition in sed to replace the above string

Comment: I think if you adopt enrico.bacis approach, with an anchor and an optional trailing slash mentioned by Mat, you will be heading in the right direction... `sed -i -e 's|^/a/d/f/\?|/a/d/f/g|g' a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with awk

```
awk -F/ -vOFS="/" '$5="g"' file
```

With sed

```
sed -r 's|(/a/d/f)/?|\1/g|' file
```

#### Output

```
/a/d/f/g
/a/d/f/g
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just:

```
sed -i -r 's|/a/d/f/?|/a/d/f/g|' a
```

Example:

```
$ cat a.txt
/a/d/f
/a/d/f/
$ sed -i -r 's|/a/d/f/?|/a/d/f/g|' a.txt
$ cat a.txt
/a/d/f/g
/a/d/f/g
```

Comment: sed -i -e 's|/a/d/f|/a/d/f/g|g' a.txt

$ more a.txt
/a/d/f/g
/a/d/f/g/

 i need it to be like /a/d/f/g

Comment: The `-e` and `g` at the end are unneeded.

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions, I improved it

Answer (score 1):

This should work if your actual input matches the example:

```
sed 's!f/\?$!f/g!' input_file
```

*Gives:*

```
/a/d/f/g
/a/d/f/g
```

Comment: You've typed sed twice.

Comment: Thanks a lot.yes this is absolutely correct. How can we replace the only the above string excluding other strings in the file?

Comment: But it won' check for the previous characters. And why there is two sed's?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i -e 's_^/a/d/f/\{0,1\}$_&/g_' a.txt
```

- use another separator in `s///` action (here `_`) to allow the use of `/` as normal character
- use delimiter (`^` and `$`) to limit to your exact sequence
- use (not mandatory) the `&` because you just *add* something to existant in replacment pattern.

I assume that there are more line than those 2 only. If not the case a simple `s_$_/g_` is enough

Comment: This will only add the g to one of the lines, also as i commented in another answer the `-e` is not needed.

Comment: oops not see the ended `/` (i adapt the reply), you are right for both info. `-e` is not mandatory on most linux distro